product order not added laravel api
i am a beginner level programmer of laravel.while developing a warehouse management project i had a problem. order table table is storing successfully but product order table data is not saving.i don't know what was the problem with code snippt . this project consist of product and client and order. order and product having a many to many relationship. can some on help me resolve the error and try to add the data into the table.what i tried so far i attached below.while tested via postmon order table data added product order table data not added
Order Controller
public function store($data)
    {

        // insert order to order table

        $order = Order::create($data);

    $products = $data['products'];

    foreach ($products as $productData) {
        $orderProduct = new ProductOrder();
        $orderProduct->product_id = $productData['product_id'];
        $orderProduct->qty = $productData['qty'];
        $orderProduct->order_id = $order->id;
        
        $orderProduct->save();

        // reduce the stock level
        $product = Product::where('id', $productData['product_id'])->first();
        $product->stock_level = $product->stock_level - $productData['qty'];
        $product->save();
    }

        return  $order;
    }

ProductOrder
class ProductOrder extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "product_orders";

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_id',
        'order_id',
        'qty',
    ];

    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function order()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}

Order
class Order extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "orders";


    protected $fillable = [
        'order_number',
        'total',
        'client_id',  
    ];

    public function client()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Client::class);
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot('qty');
    }

}

Product
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $primary_key = "id";
    protected $table = "products";

    protected $fillable = [
        'product_code',
        'product_name',
        'stock_level',
        'price',
        'category_id',
    ];

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Order::class)->withPivot('qty');
   
    }


    
}


Did you get any specific error?dd($products) to check whether it has all the data that will be stored into the productOrder table.

dd($products) i did check it but no result api result

What does it shows dd($products)? From this you will get idea what has gone wrong since You have mentioned that order is being stored but not the productOrder. So edit your question and share what did you find in  dd($products)?It is way to debug the issue not an way to solve it.

if you already have relationship between order and products and looks like you want to  assign products between info to your oders you should
first store order like you did and through $orders variable from $oder= Oder::create(); and
$order->products()->sync([ $$productData['product_id'] => ['qty' => $productData['qty']], $$productData['product_id'] => ['qty' => $productData['qty']] ]); as you have made a pivot table to store other value.
this will store order_id product id and quantity

can you write the full code

its better you try it yourself i have attached some link go through them and try yourself .
this is for your pivot table https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships
and since you are making multiple changes in database make sure to use https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/database#manually-using-transactions
this have enough info i am sure you can do it on your own. good luck.
and also make sure you have product id while attaching to your pivot table

public function store($data)
{
    // Insert order into the order table
    $order = Order::create($data);

    $products = $data['products'];

    foreach ($products as $productData) {
        // Attach products to the order with quantity
        $order->products()->attach($productData['product_id'], ['qty' => $productData['qty']]);

        // Reduce the stock level
        $product = Product::find($productData['product_id']);
        $product->stock_level -= $productData['qty'];
        $product->save();
    }

    return $order;
}


order_id i didn't get

i did what you are did the way still same error.order_id you didn't put

show me the result you're getting in $data

Stack 200 OK  i got the result on postman

only order data added but product order not added when i check the database table
